# React/Mobx: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, mobx, mobx-react

What I'm trying to do;

- Pull data from API and insert it into a mobx store called UserStore
- Retrieve and display User Store Data in another component

***This is my UserStore.ts***

```
import { observable, action } from 'mobx';
import { getUser } from '../api/api';

export class UserStore {

@observable users: [{
    firstName: string;
    surName: string;
    dateofBirth: string;
    ethnicity: string,
    maritalStatus: string,
}]


@action 
loadUser = () => {
    getUser().then(users => this.users = users)
    console.log(this.users)
}
}
```

***This is my Api call to retrieve data.ts***
This backend API is running as a separate project on Visual Studio, I have checked it is working and I am able to receive a 200 response when requesting through postman.

```
export const getUser = ():Promise<[{ firstName: string; surName: string; dateofBirth: string; ethnicity: string; maritalStatus: string; }]> => {
return fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/personalInfo/1').then(res => res.json())
}
```

***This is my RootStateContext so that I am able to use the Store everywhere in the project***

```
import React from 'react';
import { UserStore } from '../stores/UserStore';

type RootStateContextValue = {
    userStore: UserStore;
};

const RootStateContext = React.createContext<RootStateContextValue>({} as. 
RootStateContextValue);

const userStore = new UserStore();

export const RootStateProvider: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<{}>> = ({ children }) => {
    return <RootStateContext.Provider value={{ userStore }}> {children} 
</RootStateContext.Provider>;
};

export const useRootStore = () => React.useContext(RootStateContext);
```

***This is my index.tsx***

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './App';
import { RootStateProvider } from './context/RootStateContext';

import './css/main.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter basename={'myCareer'}>
        <RootStateProvider>
            <App />
        </RootStateProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

***This is my PersonalInformation_Card.tsx where I am trying to map the data from UserStore and display it***

```
export default function PersonalInformation_Paper() {
const { userStore } = useRootStore();

return useObserver(() => (
    <>
        <div>
            {userStore.users.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <option key={user.firstName} value={user.firstName}>
                        {user.firstName}
                    </option>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    </>
));
}
```

In this page I keep getting the error; TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I think this is because the API call is not being executed, and the store is not being populated so there is nothing to map, however I am not sure. Can anyone help?

Thanks

*Edit to show console.log(userStore) as requested

[image]

*Edit to show console.log(userStore) when changing

```
    @observable users: [{
    firstName: string;
    surName: string;
    dateofBirth: string;
    ethnicity: string,
    maritalStatus: string,
}]
```

Into

```
    @observable users = [{
    firstName: '',
    surName: '',
    dateofBirth: '',
    ethnicity: '',
    maritalStatus: '',
}]
```

[image]

Comment: can you show result of   `console`?  `console.log(userStore)`

Comment: @zahrazamani Added at the bottom of the question as requested

Comment: users is undefined That's why it gives an error

Comment: The `map ` is done on the array otherwise it will give an error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  export default function PersonalInformation_Paper() {
        const { userStore } = useRootStore();
        
        return useObserver(() => (
    console.log(userStore)
            <>
                <div>
                    {userStore.users && userStore.users!=undefined ? userStore.users.map((user) => {
                        return (
                            <option key={user.firstName} value={user.firstName}>
                                {user.firstName}
                            </option>
                        );
                    }) : []}
                </div>
            </>
        ));
        

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The error is still appearing and the console.log is still showing users: undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your Store `users` implicitly set to undefined. Even if you call api later the first render will fail because of it.

You need to initialize them with empty array or check for existence:

```
type User = { firstName: string; surName: string; dateofBirth: string; ethnicity: string, maritalStatus: string, };

export class UserStore {
  // Like that
  @observable users: Array<User> = [];
  
  // ...
}
```

or check that users array exists inside your component:

```
export default function PersonalInformation_Paper() {
  const { userStore } = useRootStore();

  return useObserver(() => (
    <> 
      {userStore.users ? 
        <div>
            {userStore.users.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <option key={user.firstName} value={user.firstName}>
                        {user.firstName}
                    </option>
                );
            })}
        </div>
        : 'Loading...'}
    </>
  ));
}
```

Comment: 'You need to initalize with empty array', I did this in UserStore.ts     @observable users: [{
        firstName: string;
        surName: string;
        dateofBirth: string;
        ethnicity: string,
        maritalStatus: string,
    }]

Comment: I have tried your answer, it gets rid of the error, however users remains undefined in the console log, and the loading..... is present on the screen

Comment: It's not initialization with array, it's Typescript interface information that field `users` will be the type of `[{ firstName: string; surName: string; dateofBirth: string; ethnicity: string, maritalStatus: string, }]`

Comment: As for `console.log` you have a type and you are logging outside of promise, it won't work. You need to invoke log inside `then`

Comment: Is it ok to initialise like so;    @observable users = [{
        firstName: '',
        surName: '',
        dateofBirth: '',
        ethnicity: '',
        maritalStatus: '',
    }]?

Comment: If this is your intent to have 1 user with empty information then it is perfectly fine. But if you want to fetch users from somewhere then at the start you should have empty array because, well, you have not fetched any users yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227163/discussion-between-md9-and-danila).